# Call to built-in matlab functions (repmap, ones) in vectorized form

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector, vectorization

I am currently trying to start using Matlab in a more elegant way by replacing loops with vectorized function calls. However, I am not quite able to make the transition in some cases. One of them is shown below:

```
for i = 1:3
 ones(i,i)
end
```

I tried

```
i = 1:3
ones(i,i)
%or
ones([i,i])
```

but instead of giving me 3 different matrices, I get a 6D matrix, because i is just merely concatenated to [1,2,3,1,2,3]. How can I achieve what I intend to do, which is

```
[1]

[1 1;
1 1]

[1 1 1;
1 1 1;
1 1 1]
```

Similarly, I would make the following call:

```
x = zeros(3)
i = 1:3
x(i,1:1) = repmat(i,1,i)
```

What I would like to see is:

```
x = 
[1 0 0;
2 2 0;
3 3 3]
```

The first question just involves how to call funtions in a vectorized form and the second is more towards dynamic matrix or vector indexing using vectors of indices.
I did read the Matlab documentation on Vectorization, but it did not quite help me with this specific issue.

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: What's the expected output for the first case?

Comment: @Divakar Sorry, I edited the expected output!

Answer (score 1):

For the first case,

```
out = arrayfun(@(n) ones(n),1:3,'Uni',0) %// Not a vectorized solution though! 
                      %// It is not possible to have a vectorized solution
                      %// as you are looking to have three different matrices
[x1,x2,x3] = deal(out{:}) %// save into different variables
```

Output -

```
x1 =
     1
x2 =
     1     1
     1     1
x3 =
     1     1     1
     1     1     1
     1     1     1
```

---

For the second case,

```
ii = 1:3;
x =  tril(repmat(ii',[1 3]))
```

Or this -

```
ii = 1:3;
x = bsxfun(@ge,[1:3]',1:3).*repmat(ii',[1 3])
```

Or this -

```
ii = 1:3;
x = repmat(ii',[1 3]);
x(bsxfun(@lt,[1:3]',1:3))=0;
```

Output -

```
x =
     1     0     0
     2     2     0
     3     3     3
```

Comment: I like the solution to the first case, but I was hoping that this would also be possible in a vectorized form.
I am not so happy with the 2nd solution. The x = zeros(3) and hence the 0s in x where just to initialize the vector and to be able to index into x. I don't require a lower triangular matrix. What I look for is to call repmat in vectorized form (multiple times with different values and lenghts) and to catch the results in a single array (maybe cellarray for that matter). Similar to a call like x(1:5) = (1:5).^2, just with a built-in function (repmat in that case) and varying lengths.

Comment: @TheodorBecker For the first case, as I said since you need three different variables as outputs and moreoever since they are of different sizes, purely vectorized solution isn't possible. For the second case, when you said - `"repmat in vectorized form (multiple times with different values and lenghts)"`, do you mean to use `repmat` in a loop and use different values for each new iteration? If so, then that won't be a vectorized solution.

Comment: Yes, I guess that in this case this would be identical to using a loop and iterating through.

Comment: @TheodorBecker Not sure if the question has answered all the queries of the question, but if it has, consider accepting it?